# I want to alter column name dynamic in existing table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know the reason why the error is coming I

```
 $newarr = [];
  if(count($_POST['dynamic_field'])){
    foreach($_POST['dynamic_field'] as $key=>$value)
     {
      $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE tbl_order ADD '.$key.' varchar(255)');
      $newarr[$key] =json_encode($value);
     } 
  }
```

just want to know to logic.

Comment: More importantly - why do you need to add a new column - this is an easy way to make your application fail at some point.

Comment: because i have dynamic form so user can add dynamic field

Comment: Have you considered using JSON fields for the data, or even an EAV type design (you should find more info with a google search)

Comment: I am a beginner  and simply want to store data

Comment: This would be open to SQL injections. What is the error? I don't see why a user would need to have a field, just store their value in the DB. Have column `userinput` or whatever it is and write the data they send.

Comment: could please help me before altering the table how can I check that column is already in the table or not

Comment: What is the actual question here? You say that you know why "the error" is coming, but you haven't said _what_ error, _when_ you get it or _where_ it's thrown. Is the question how to check if a column exists (which you only mentioned for the first time in the comment above), or is it something else? If you want help with some logic, you need to explain _in detail_ what your actual issue is. Very unclear and vague "question" atm.

Comment: You can just generic fields such as *userfield1*, *userfieldname1*....  where the first has the value and the second is the name that the user wants.